# Excel: Scroll bar in middle of sheet?

Tags: excel, debugging, scrollbar

So I opened an old workbook I've had for many years now.  It's a bit of a database for digital album lists and such.

And when I opened it I saw this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTTdD.png)Random scroll bar in middle of screen

I do not understand how the heck it even got there.  And it doesn't seem to be a global thing -- when I opened a new sheet it isn't there.  And when I copy the contents of the sheets from this excel file to a new one, the scroll bar doesn't copy over.

any thoughts on how to make this go away?

Comment: Try unfreezing any frozen rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: It was a ghost scroll bar.

When I went to check the file again another day the invisible scroll bar had disappeared.

This might be due to the file being transferred from another computer.  I don't see the bar there anymore.

If anyone *does* face this issue, if you copy the contents of any sheet to a brand new workbook or sheet in the same workbook, the invisible scroll bar also disappears

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).